# How to fix "Leverage browser caching" error from Page Speed plugin

Tags: optimization, cache, page-speed

I'm using the [Page Speed Firebug plug-in](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) to check my sites.

But I don't know how to fix the "Leverage browser caching" error, since I don't know you specify a cache lifetime to the browser in images and css files.

Comment: i m also facing same problem on IIS 6.0 . Plz help me.

Comment: @Anuja - Please take a look at the accepted answer's link and, if the information provided does not help you resolve the issue, post a new question describing the issue and the actions you have taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're using IIS, so you probably want to start with [this TechNet document](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770661%28WS.10%29.aspx).